# RObin problem (Laplace equation)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let
$\Delta u = 0 $, 
$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial v}(x) + \alpha u(x) = 0 $
be the Laplace equation with Robin conditions.
How do I prove it has at most one solution.

If I could prove that any two solutions differs only by one constant, I would prove this using the unicity of the the solution for Dirichlet problem...
But I couldn't prove this until now.
THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $\alpha$ is a positive constant. Take two solutions $u,v$. Then, test both weak formulations with the difference $u-v$ and take the difference of these weak formulations. You should end with
$$
\int_\Omega \lvert \nabla (u - v)\rvert^2 \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial\Omega} (u - v)^2 \, \mathrm{d} s = 0.
$$
This shows (I do not reveal the precise arguments here) $u = v$.

Comment: I found the same equality, without the square in the second integration.

Comment: Now, I could see!